# Group by - MS SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have table like

```
Status  - Count
DELIVRD - 68926
Failed  - 6369
EXP-SMS-TMOUT   - 101
EXP-NW-TMOUT    - 97
EXP-MEM-EXCD    - 17
EXP-NW-FAIL - 109
EXP-HDST-BUSY   - 113
EXP-AbsSubs - 5732
```

& I want result like

```
Delivered - 68926
Failed  -   6369
EXP - 6169   [Total(EXP-SMS-TMOUT,EXP-NW-TMOUT,EXP-MEM-EXCD,EXP-NW-FAIL,EXP-HDST-BUSY,EXP-AbsSubs)]
```

How we can do this using group by. Please share the query asap.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT 
  CASE WHEN Status LIKE 'EXP%' THEN 'EXP' ELSE Status END
, SUM([Count]) as [Count]
FROM Table1
GROUP BY CASE WHEN Status LIKE 'EXP%' THEN 'EXP' ELSE Status END
```

[SQLFiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/19b00/2)